# Migrating Meteor from 0.8.x to a Cordova Release on windows

Tags: windows, cordova, meteor

on [meteor hackpad - Getting Started With Cordova article](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Getting-Started-With-Cordova-Z5n6zkVB1xq) it says:

To migrate your existing app, you need to migrate to 0.9.x first. If 0.9.x is not available yet, migrate to a 0.9.0 RC by typing in your app folder:
meteor update --release 0.9.0-rc11

This will migrate your tool and core packages to The New Meteor Packaging System (tm)! After that feel free to migrate to a Cordova release:
meteor update --release CORDOVA-PREVIEW@3

I tried it(on windows)strong text but I get :

**0.9.0-rc11: unknown release.**

Comment: Meteor isn't yet available with the new build system on windows. It may take a while still.

Comment: I think Akshat is correct. I never heard of maintainers of Windows port (those people are awesome btw) working on 0.9.x port

Comment: Only release candidates of O.9 have been released, and they have been coming thick and fast - I only have the time to port official releases. Given the substantial changes to the packaging system it may take me a little while to get things working - but rest assured it should be available soon.